# Converting column to rows in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, unpivot

I have a table like this:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| ID | AR_SCORE | ER_SCORE | FS_SCORE | CPF_SCORE | IF_SCORE | IS_SCORE |
+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|  1 |       25 |       35 |       45 |        55 |       65 |       75 |
|  2 |       95 |       85 |       75 |        65 |       55 |       45 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

And I need to extract this:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| ID |  SCORE   | VALUE |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | AR_SCORE |    25 |
|  1 | ER_SCORE |    35 |
|  2 | AR_SCORE |    95 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

I read many questions about how to use pivoting in oracle but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion from columns into rows is actually an `UNPIVOT`. Since you are using Oracle 11g there are a few ways that you can get the result.

The first way would be using a combination of `SELECT yourcolumn FROM...UNION ALL`:

```
select ID, 'AR_SCORE' as Score, AR_SCORE as value
from yourtable
union all
select ID, 'ER_SCORE' as Score, ER_SCORE as value
from yourtable
union all
select ID, 'FS_SCORE' as Score, FS_SCORE as value
from yourtable
union all
select ID, 'IF_SCORE' as Score, IF_SCORE as value
from yourtable
union all
select ID, 'IS_SCORE' as Score, IS_SCORE as value
from yourtable
order by id
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93488/3). Using UNION ALL was how you needed to unpivot data prior to Oracle 11g, but starting in that version the [`UNPIVOT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) function was implemented.  This will get you the same result with fewer lines of code:

```
select ID, Score, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for Score in (AR_SCORE, ER_SCORE, FS_SCORE, IF_SCORE, IS_SCORE)
) un
order by id
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93488/4/0). Both will give a result:

```
| ID |    SCORE | VALUE |
|----|----------|-------|
|  1 | AR_SCORE |    25 |
|  1 | FS_SCORE |    45 |
|  1 | IS_SCORE |    75 |
|  1 | IF_SCORE |    65 |
|  1 | ER_SCORE |    35 |
|  2 | FS_SCORE |    75 |
|  2 | IS_SCORE |    45 |
|  2 | ER_SCORE |    85 |
|  2 | IF_SCORE |    55 |
|  2 | AR_SCORE |    95 |
```

Comment: Really good. I'm using the second way. and I see that automatically does not select the null values which is good. But if in the future I'll need to have the null values, is there a way?